# Run JUnit Test from a java web application

Tags: java, testing, junit, web

Is it possible to run JUnit Tests from a java web application (on a Tomcat server) ?

How can I with a click on a link, launch the instantiation of an object ? or the call to a method ?

Thank you very much.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 5):

Sure, although I'm not sure why you'd want to.

See the [cookbook example](http://junit.sourceforge.net/doc/cookbook/cookbook.htm), nutshell:

```
org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.runClasses(TestClass1.class, ...);
```

Obviously you'd need to deploy your test classes so they're available on the classpath, and convert from a string class name to an actual `Class`.

You'd likely also need to scan for annotations or convention-based class names; there are a variety of ways to do that including things like the [reflections](http://code.google.com/p/reflections/) library.

IMO it'd be easier to set up a continuous integration (CI) server like [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) or [CruiseControl](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/) etc. and get a complete package, but it depends on what your needs actually are.

Answer (score 0):

There a number of JUnit-based frameworks that can assist with web testing.

[Jwebunit](http://jwebunit.sourceforge.net/)

[Canoo Webtest](http://www.junit.org/node/32)

[HttpUnit](http://httpunit.sourceforge.net/)

[HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: I think the OP was talking about launching junit tests from a webapp, not testing a webapp with junit.